# 64base decoding a secret key with python just gives a new code

Tags: python, base64

I'm trying to decode a textstring with python3, but it doesn't com out right. What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> import base64
>>> print(base64.b64decode(b'Mw2aXjiDQABoNi5jB09ie8iTkET4t6JiQJSh+/jIceY='))
>>> b'3\r\x9a^8\x83@\x00h6.c\x07Ob{\xc8\x93\x90D\xf8\xb7\xa2b@\x94\xa1\xfb\xf8\xc8q\xe6'
```

Best regards from Kresten

Comment: What makes you think that the result isn't right? What result did you expect?

Comment: I expect to get : b'testapp'

Comment: then try to feed it `'dGVzdGFwcA=='` ?

Comment: The only thing you're doing wrong is giving it the wrong input.

Comment: You might check if your "secret" was salted - that would explain why it is so much longer then your text you want to get... read [Crypto Salt Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) - and if it was salted you wont be able to decode it easily

Comment: I better go and read the docs more carefully. Thanks

Comment: The docs: "secret: an optional secret key that is used to generate a HMAC-SHA256 hash of the request body so the receiver can verify authenticity of the webhook" I don't know what to do with it. I found an  example of how to encrypt but not the other way. Any help is very appreciated.